# Add variable at the end of links (only without REL-attr)

Tags: javascript, parameters, hyperlink, append

I hope somebody can help me... I try to grab a parameter, which is saved in the head of a html-site, and add this parameter to all links on the site, which have no "rel='gallery'"-attribut. some links have allready other GET-parameters. It looks like this:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ParameterNew = "test";
</script>
</head>
[...]
Search: <a href="http://google.com">Google</a><br/>
Social Media: <a href="http://facebook.com?show=start">Facebook</a>
<br/><br/>
<a rel="gallery" href="img/1.jpg">Gallery Link 1</a><br/>
<a rel="gallery" href="img/2.jpg">Gallery Link 2</a><br/>
```

So I try to append the ParameterNew behind all links, which have no rel-attribut.

At the end it has to looks lie this:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ParameterNew = "test";
</script>
</head>
[...]
Search: <a href="http://google.com?parameter=test">Google</a><br/>
Social Media: <a href="http://facebook.com?show=start&parameter=test">Facebook</a>
<br/><br/>
<a rel="gallery" href="img/1.jpg">Gallery Link 1</a><br/>
<a rel="gallery" href="img/2.jpg">Gallery Link 2</a><br/>
```

I wrote this one. It only replace the innerHTML (such as an example):

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    if (links[i].target !== "_blank")
        links[i].innerHTML = 'test';
}
```

I only have problem to append the parameter... Maybe someone can help? thanx

Answer (score 1):

This is a reasonably simple solution that takes into account your exact example conditions.  That is, it assumes you have simple links so that all that needs to be done is check which connector to use in adding the parameter.  If your links can contain parameters that are links, you'll need to do something more complex to figure out whether to use a `?` or `&` to append the parameter.

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    if (links[i].rel != 'gallery') {
        var href = links[i].href,
            connector = '?';
        if (href && href.match(/\?/)) {
           connector = '&';
        }
        links[i].href = href + connector + 'parameter=' + ParameterNew;
    }
}
```